# lazy-load database '../R/NymbulCredentials.rdb' is corrupt

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to install a package from GitHub in support of deploying an app to shinyapps.io. If I download the package onto my machine, then it installs without issue.  However, if I execute the command (in RStudio):

```
devtools::install_github(repo="rlmoore0/NMDeploy", subdir="NymbulCredentials")
```

then I get an error message:  **Error in (function (n)  : 
  lazy-load database '../R/NymbulCredentials.rdb' is corrupt**

This GitHub repo is public, so anyone can try running this command from within R/RStudio with devtools installed.  I am on a Windows box running R 3.6.3, Win10.

Any suggestions?

I have looked at questions from other people with similar problems and based on the responses to them, I have tried:

- Closing and restarting R/RStudio
- Executing the command `devtools::unload("NymbulCredentials")`
- Executing the command `unloadNamespace("NymbulCredentials")`
- Removing the installation library the package is being installed to as referenced by `.libPaths()` and trying a fresh directory as the installation location.

The error still persists.